# Kth missing positive integer

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

Given an array arr of positive integers sorted in a strictly increasing order, and an integer k.

Find the kth positive integer that is missing from this array.

Example 1:

Input: arr = [2,3,4,7,11], k = 5
Output: 9
Explanation: The missing positive integers are [1,5,6,8,9,10,12,13,...]. The 5th missing positive integer is 9.
Example 2:

Input: arr = [1,2,3,4], k = 2
Output: 6
Explanation: The missing positive integers are [5,6,7,...]. The 2nd missing positive integer is 6.

Constraints:

1 <= arr.length <= 1000

1 <= arr[i] <= 1000

1 <= k <= 1000

arr[i] < arr[j] for 1 <= i < j <= arr.length

I have submitted this code but this is showing TLE error.Please explain why TLE is occurring and how to solve this.

```
    class Solution {
public:
    int findKthPositive(vector<int>& arr, int k) {
        vector<int> ans;
        int count=0,i=1,flag=0;
        
        while(count<k)
        {
            int start=0,end=arr.size()-1;
            while(start<=end)
            {
                int mid=start+(end-start)/2;
                if(arr[mid]==i) 
                    flag=1;
                else if(arr[mid]>i) 
                    end=mid-1; 
                else 
                    start=mid+1;

            }
            if(flag==0)
            {
                ans.push_back(i); 
                count++;
            }
            i++;
        } 
        return ans[k-1];
    }
};
```

Comment: Why Are you finding Mid. could you explain the logic. it feels to me like over complicated. maybe a direct approach will be faster compared to this as the given array is already sorted.

Comment: I am searching for the element i using binary search

Comment: can you post the question link as well. may be edit your question. I think the TLE is due to this "logn" extra complexity because logic seems fine

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/kth-missing-positive-number/description/

Comment: The simplest solution will have the time complexity of either O(n) or O(k) and space complexity of O(1). The approach is to have 1 ```for``` loop to go from 1 to 1000,  and 1 ```counter``` that counts the current total missing integer. Once the ```counter``` equals ```k``` in the ```for``` loop,  that index ```i``` of the ```for``` loop is the answer.  This approach does not require the binary search logic.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two problems in your code.

First, the `flag` is not reset to 0 for each loop leading to infinite loop

Second, when a number is found in the array, the code will be stuck in the while loop too because there is no break statement.

Here is a code that works. I've move the `flag` declaration inside the loop and added a `break` statement when a number is found inside the vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class Solution {
public:
    int findKthPositive(vector<int>& arr, int k) {
        vector<int> ans;
        int count=0,i=1;
        
        while(count<k)
        {
            int start=0,end=arr.size()-1,flag=0;
            while(start<=end)
            {
                int mid=start+(end-start)/2;
                if(arr[mid]==i) {
                    flag=1;
                    break;
                }
                else if(arr[mid]>i) 
                    end=mid-1; 
                else 
                    start=mid+1;

            }
            if(flag==0)
            {
                ans.push_back(i); 
                count++;
            }
            i++;
        } 
        return ans[k-1];
    }
};

int main() {

  std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
  Solution a;
  vector<int> testv = {2, 3, 4, 7, 11 };
  std::cout << a.findKthPositive(testv, 5) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are starting **new** binary search again and again.

Instead you would to calculate difference between `a[i]` and `i` and compare this difference with `k` - so the only loop, the only binary search for given `k` is needed, time is logarithmic

Code in Python but I hope it is understandable:

```
def findit(a, n, k):
    if a[0] > k:
        return k
    if k > a[n-1] - n:
        return k + a[n-1] - n-1

    #binary search of index of first occurrence of the least element   greater than key 
    start = 0
    end = n - 1
    while start <= end:
        mid = (start + end) // 2
        t = a[mid] - mid
        if t <= k:
            start = mid + 1
        else:
            idx = mid
            end = mid - 1
    return(k + idx)

a = [2,3,4,7,11]
for k in range(1, 9):
    print(findit(a, len(a), k))

result    
1   5   6   8   9   10   12   13
```

Comment: Why is the return for `if k > a[n-1] - n:` not just k + n?

Comment: What is the reason to return (k+idx) ? I understood that idx is the index where the first occurrence of element greater than k. But is there any logical reason why we return exactly (k+idx) ?

Comment: @Ishan Bhatt `k` missed items + place `idx` gives value `k+idx`

Answer (score 0):

you could do a bucket since those constraints are suggesting that.

```
vector<int> sorted_array;

int bucket[1000];

for (int i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
  bucket[i] = 0;
}

for (auto elem : sorted_array)
{
  bucket[elem]++;
}

int k = <user_input>;

int result = -1;
int index = 0;
for (int i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
  if (bucket[i] == 0) // missing
  {
    index++;
  }
  if (index == k)
  {
    result = i;
    break;
  }
}

if (result > 0)
{
   cout << "We have a result: " << result << endl;
}
else
{
   cout << "No result found\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, the binary searching is adding up extra time and calculation in your solution. you are adding `k x O(log n)` untill you reach desired answer.

may be try a simpler approach as the array is already sorted

```
  class Solution {
public:
    int findKthPositive(vector<int>& arr, int k) {
        // you dont need an extra array to store the `k-1` numbers

        int count=0, i=0, curr_num = 1;
        
        while (i < arr.size()){
            if (curr_num == arr[i]){
            // we compare the numbers simply with current position if it is present in arr woo-hoo otherwise increase count
                i++;
            } else {
                count++;
                if (count == k){
                    break;
                }
                
            }
            curr_num++;
        }

        if (count < k){
            while (count < k) {
                count++;
                if (count == k){
                    break;
                }
                curr_num++;
            }
            
        }

        return curr_num;
    }
};
};
```